# how to convert this?

Tags: c#, c++

hi may i know how to convert this c++ code to c#?

```
memset(device, 0, 32);
```

I tried the following :
`device = new string(Char(32));`

Is this correct?

Comment: You learn to use google: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/

Comment: You don't.  Learn about `List<T>`.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, basically, in c#, you can simply say :

```
string device = string.Empty;
```

in fact, you can even say:

```
var device = string.Empty;
```

At this point, `device` is initialized as a pointer to a string variable who's current value is `string.Empty` or `""`, with whatever amount of memory c# decides that it needs.  The amount of memory allocated to that object will be transparent to you as the .net developer.

One of the major differences between c++ and c# is that c# handles all the memory management for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks. It works exactly. I can just ignore that by putting as empy. I appreciated your reply. Thanks +1